# Live Chat Widget Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, embed

I am trying to embed code of live chat and putting it under the script tag.Here is my code...

```
window.onload = function() {
(function(w,d,u){
var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/60000|0);
var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
})(window,document,'site Url');
}
```

It successfully shows the sticky chat icon at the bottom of the page but after that it displays a message box and some text at the upper left corner for 1,2 sec and then disappears.
When I remove this script the site works normally.

Is there any problem with their script ?

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML codes so that we can help you better?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the html and it is a big file can't share it here..

Comment: Any error on dev console?

Comment: Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 and some more like these...